# JPA one-to-one recursive mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I know there's a bunch of documentation around this but I'm still a bit confused. I have the following:

```java
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private ChildEntity child;
}

@Entity
public class ChildEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")
    @JsonBackReference
    private ParentEntity parent;
}
```

So the response I get is fine:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ric",
    "child": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Soph"
    }
}
```

However, when I enter debug I'm seeing recursive behaviour..

[image]

**Why is there recursive behaviour in the entity models themselves? Is this a performance issue? Also, am I doing something wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

Are u returning **Entity** from controller?

If u are doing so please change that, add DTO's and send DTO from controller.

Comment: Yup.. this is not production code, was just a super quick sample. I can adjust my code to return a DTO but that isn't really relevant to the question. Maybe what I am asking is unclear? I am mainly interested in understanding why the entity is creating recursive references (and whether this is a bad thing and how to stop it).

Comment: U return an entity it continuously goes on giving data from the relation. Thats what was happening in your case. ParentEntity -> ChildEntity(this again contains parentEntity), which goes displaying in loop.
There is nothing wrong in the code, its just because of returning an entity. Normal practice is that they dont send Entity bec of the relation they have with other tables.

Comment: Yup, I understand it's not okay to return an entity.. It's also not relevant here. Even if I were to map the entity to a DTO, it would still have the internal recursive references on the entity before I did the mapping.. I am wondering whether there is something I am missing that is causing this (on the entity itself.. I don't care what happens after retrieving the data in this example).